# Refactoring Browser

Tags: f#, refactoring, ml

Ok, a while ago I read about a Re-factoring Browser for I think, Lisp (or maybe it was smalltalk).
This was a tool to help with re-factoring.
I was wondering if anyone knows of a free one for F#?
(seems reasonable a functional languages should be 'nice' for that kind of thing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, in principle, functional languages are great for refactoring. As far as I know, the only tool that implements some support for refactoring is this project:

- [F# Refactor](http://fsharprefactor.codeplex.com/) at CodePlex (and [downloads](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/339cbae9-911d-4f99-9033-3c3564676f45) at Visual Studio Gallery)

Currently, it supports only a few basic things, but it is using a good approach (using the F# source code to do the difficult work such as type-checking), so I tihnk it is a promising project.

Anyway, many refactorings in F# don't even need a tool support - often cutting code & pasting it into a different context is all you need. For example, I often start with just writing `let` declarations and then turn them into a type by indenting them and enclosing them in a `type` definition (as local functions).

Comment: it's not great, I mean it's OK, but absically all it does is highlght and renamve indentifiers. (it could be alot more useful, eg generating a list of functions that call a partifuclar function, or a list of line nums where an identifier is used. just to start)
But in anycase it does appear to be the best that is out there.
Thanks